# javascript overwriting my data

Tags: javascript

I am trying to write a short script to get some data. The idea is, instead of writing a lot of JavaScript files and I always need to hardcode the ID in the link I thought it must be possible to insert a variable into the link. Now I have the problem I only see the last value of my var as it looks like the var will be overwritten all time instead of simply adding the ID to the output. I hope you can help me.

Here is the code:

```
myConnector.getData = function(table, doneCallback) {
  var date = new Date();
  edate = date.toISOString().slice(0,10) + "-23-59-59";

  var ids = ["3775", "6697"]
  for ( i = 1; i < ids.length; i++)
  var id_temp  = ids[i];
  {

    $.getJSON("https://****/api/historicdata.json?id="+id_temp+"&avg=0&sdate=2016-12-12-00-00-00&edate="+edate+"&username=***&passhash=****", function(resp) {

      var feat = resp.histdata,
      tableData = []; 

      // Iterate over the JSON object
      //String id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();  
      for (var j = 0, len = feat.length; j < len; j++) {
        tableData.push({
          //"no"     : j,
          "ids" : id_temp,
          "datetime": feat[j].datetime,
          "value": feat[j].value,
          "value_raw": feat[j].value_raw,
          "coverage": feat[j].coverage,
          "coverage_raw": feat[j].coverage_raw


        });
      }

      table.appendRows(tableData);

    });

  };
  doneCallback(); 
};
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: The doneCallback() is useless as long as it is not in the asynchronous $.getJSON() part.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `id_temp` only gets set with the last value because `{` is in the wrong place.

This:

```
 var ids = ["3775", "6697"]
 for ( i = 1; i < ids.length; i++)
     var id_temp  = ids[i];

 {
```

Should be:

```
var ids = ["3775", "6697"]
for ( i = 1; i < ids.length; i++)
{
     var id_temp  = ids[i];
     //... rest of loop ...
```

Comment: Where is this last var showing? Also, did you make certain that you did not get a cached version of the JavaScript you edited? I.e., remember to Ctrl+F5 (firefox) to make sure your new code is running and not a cached copy.

Comment: This is one problem, but by no means the only one. The fundamental problem is how he is handling the sequence of async calls.

Answer (score 1):

its the issue that your entire code is not inside for loop , your for loop only have one line

use

```
 var ids = ["3775", "6697"]
 for ( i = 1; i < ids.length; i++)
 {
   var id_temp  = ids[i];
    $.getJSON("https://****/api/historicdata.json?id="+id_temp+"&avg=0&sdate=2016-12-12-00-00-00&edate="+edate+"&username=***&passhash=****", function(resp) {
```

Comment: This is one problem, but by no means the only one.

Comment: i agree with you , but by the question OP says that "javascript overwriting my data" and the answer is for that , why its overwritten or why only last id is been used.

Comment: Well, it is the first time I need to script java, so sorry if I miss something or do not understand correctly. the sxript is a web Data connector which I use for Tableau. I have installed a Simulator on my PC where I can run the script to see the output. And all time I am running this script I see as an output the ID 6697. I switched the Ids just to be sure it is an overwriting problem and the result was the last ID again was shown. This is why I am thinking I am overwriting the data